# MacBook Pro with Thunderbolt display - Why do programs always start on the laptop screen?

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt-display

I have an MBP Retina with a Thunderbolt display. I have them arranged non-mirrored with the thunderbolt display in front of me (bluetooth keyboard) and the laptop to the right.

I'm using the TB display for most things and the laptop for 'overflow' when needed.

The problem is that whenever I start a new program it appears first on the laptop screen and I have to drag it onto the Thunderbolt display.

Why is it doing this, and how can I have it start programs on the thunderbolt display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are 2 ways to help you solve you issue

1. set the TB display as the "main" display. You can drag the "Menu bar" to the TB display in "System preferences"->Display setting, please refer the screen shot below. As you said the external TB display is most thing, so I suggest you this way.
   [image]
2. You can setup App launch in individual desktop or display. Right-Click the App icon in the Dock and choice "Option",set the App launch at the display you want.

Comment: Actually, every display and space has menu and dock itsself.